# jQuery not recognizing appended HTML

Tags: jquery, append

Quite new to jQuery so exercise patience with me :)

I think this should be a quick one: On clicking .color, I've appended some basic HTML to a page with the class .selected. When I hover on any div.color with the html (.selected) appended inside of it, I want to add some CSS to .selected to give it a hover on state, by using

```
$('.color').toggle( 
    function(){
        $('.color').empty('span'),
        $(this).append("<span class='selected'></span>")
    },
    function() {
        $('.color').empty('span');
    })

$('.color').click( function(){
    $('.color').toggle;
})

$('.color').has('.selected').hover(
        function(){
            $(".color span").css('background-position', '0px -24px');
        },
        function() {
            $(".color span").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        })
```

The problem is that jQuery isn't recognizing that the appended html exists. I've manually inserted the HTML and it works perfectly, but through .append it doesn't cooperate.

Thanks

EDIT: Demo here: http://judsoncollier.com/DEMO/

Comment: It looks to me like the span you're appending has no size and thus couldn't show a background image.

Comment: That's not the issue. here's a demo. http://judsoncollier.com/DEMO/

Comment: Care to describe what the demo is supposed to do?  Is there any reason you aren't just using the `:hover` pseudo class in your CSS rather than using javascript?  And for your javascript, is there any reason why you're adding a span rather than just adding a class to the existing object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery live event inorder to attach events to the modified html content(that were injected into dom after the jquery ready function was fired).I have modified taken ur code and made it work.Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/zySNn/ Hope it helps.

Comment: _"You have to use jquery live"_ - You don't have to, in fact `live()` is deprecated from version 1.7+, in favour of `.on()`. Even for pre 1.7 you should be using `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

since you have appended the class="selected", you can manipulate the class behavior by adding this class in your css file for hover.

```
.selected:hover{
//your css
}
```

you won't need jquery to do this and it would save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event handlers using live() method.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with using jQuery .on() in the past (plus only for jQuery version 1.7 I think).  Try using jQuery's .live() method on your ".selected" selector like this:

```
    $('.selected').live("mouseenter",function(){
```

//do stuff
});

```
    $('.selected').live("mouseleave",function(){
```

//do stuff
});

Comment: `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 in favor of [`on()`](http://api..jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @Purmou: I think that we are all aware of that.  Please read the post in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `.click()` or `.hover()` methods (or `.keyup()`, etc.), jQuery assigns a handler to any elements that match the selector (`'.color'` in your case) *at that moment*. It doesn't apply to any elements added in the future or to existing elements that don't currently match but which are later modified. Neither does it automatically remove the click handler from elements changed to no longer match that selector.

Fortunately there are three ways to assign a handler such that it will work for elements added in the future: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `.on()`, otherwise use `.delegate()` because `.live()` is deprecated (and I mention it only for completeness). In general terms the way all three work is they assign a handler to a container element and then when the event occurs they check to see if the target element matches the selector you originally specified. This means that all three will let you define your handler once and have it automatically apply to elements added in the future. (Again for completeness I should mention that `.on()` does more than this depending on the parameters you pass it - for full info read the doco page.)

So anyway, to fix your code try this:

```
// if your elements have an appropriate container, then specify it
// like so:
$('#yourcontainer').on('hover', '.color .selected', function(){
      $(".color span").css('background-position', '0px -24px');
},
function() {
      $(".color span").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
});

// OR, if you don't have a container and don't want to add one
// just specify document:
$(document).on('hover', '.color .selected', function(){
   // etc
```

Though having said that I'm not sure if you can assign "hover" with `.on()`, `.delegate()` or `.live()`: you might have to assign "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" instead.

**EDIT:** Regarding what you're doing appending an empty span: you seem to be trying to use this like a flag on your element. A *much* better way to do that is to simply add and remove another class to your element using [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).